# Custom View unable to apply padding

Tags: android, button, padding, android-custom-view

I have created a custom View which extends button, and creates a simple Drawable background from a color that I give it.

Not specifying the padding results in no padding.
Specifying the padding in the XML declaration of an individual FlatButton results in no padding.
Setting the padding programatically does not have any effect.

What gives?

```
public class FlatButton extends Button {

private int buttonColor;
private int pressedButtonColor = -1;
private int cornerRadius;
private int paddingLeft;
private int paddingTop;
private int paddingRight;
private int paddingBottom;

private Drawable pressedDrawable;
private Drawable unpressedDrawable;

public FlatButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public FlatButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
    parseAttrs(context, attrs);
}

public FlatButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
    parseAttrs(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    refresh();
}

public void refresh() {
    int alpha = Color.alpha(buttonColor);
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(buttonColor, hsv);
    hsv[2] *= 0.8f;
    //if shadow color was not defined, generate shadow color = 120% brightness
    if (pressedButtonColor == -1) {
        pressedButtonColor = Color.HSVToColor(alpha, hsv);
    }
    //Create pressed background and unpressed background drawables

    if (this.isEnabled()) {
        pressedDrawable = createDrawable(cornerRadius, pressedButtonColor);
        unpressedDrawable = createDrawable(cornerRadius, buttonColor);
    } else {
        Color.colorToHSV(buttonColor, hsv);
        hsv[1] *= 0.25f; // saturation component
        int disabledColor = Color.HSVToColor(alpha, hsv);
        // Disabled button does not have shadow
        pressedDrawable = createDrawable(cornerRadius, disabledColor);
        unpressedDrawable = createDrawable(cornerRadius, disabledColor);
    }
    Drawable drawable = createStateListDrawable(pressedDrawable, unpressedDrawable);
    updateBackground(drawable);
    setPadding();
}

private void setPadding() {
    this.setPadding(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
}

private Drawable createStateListDrawable(Drawable pressedDrawable, Drawable unpressedDrawable) {

    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, pressedDrawable);
    stateListDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, unpressedDrawable);
    return stateListDrawable;
}

private Drawable createDrawable(int radius, int color) {
    float[] outerRadius = new float[]{radius, radius, radius, radius, radius, radius, radius, radius};
    RoundRectShape roundRectShape = new RoundRectShape(outerRadius, null, null);
    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(roundRectShape);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
    return shapeDrawable;
}

private void init() {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    if (resources == null) {
        return;
    }

    this.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.flatbutton_default_text_color));
    this.setAllCaps(resources.getBoolean(R.bool.flatbutton_default_textallcaps));
    this.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    this.setTextSize(14f);
    this.setHeight(resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.flatbutton_default_height));

    this.buttonColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
    this.cornerRadius = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.flatbutton_default_corner_radius);

    //setPadding();
}

private void parseAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FlatButton, 0, 0);

    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FlatButton);
    if (typedArray == null) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < typedArray.getIndexCount(); i++) {
        int attr = typedArray.getIndex(i);
        if (attr == R.styleable.FlatButton_buttonColor) {
            buttonColor = typedArray.getColor(attr, R.color.colorPrimary);
        } else if (attr == R.styleable.FlatButton_cornerRadius) {
            cornerRadius = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, R.dimen.flatbutton_default_corner_radius);
        }
    }
    typedArray.recycle();

    int[] attrsArray = new int[]{
            android.R.attr.paddingLeft,  // 0
            android.R.attr.paddingRight, // 1
    };
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
    if (ta == null) return;
    paddingLeft = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0);
    paddingRight = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(1, 0);
    ta.recycle();

    //Get paddingTop, paddingBottom
    int[] attrsArray2 = new int[]{
            android.R.attr.paddingTop,   // 0
            android.R.attr.paddingBottom,// 1
    };
    TypedArray ta1 = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray2);
    if (ta1 == null) return;
    paddingTop = ta1.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0);
    paddingBottom = ta1.getDimensionPixelSize(1, 0);
    ta1.recycle();
}

private void updateBackground(Drawable background) {
    if (background == null) return;
    //Set button background
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        this.setBackground(background);
    } else {
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
}


public int getButtonColor() {
    return buttonColor;
}

public void setButtonColor(int buttonColor) {
    this.buttonColor = buttonColor;
}

public int getCornerRadius() {
    return cornerRadius;
}

public void setCornerRadius(int cornerRadius) {
    this.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
}

public int getPressedButtonColor() {
    return pressedButtonColor;
}

public void setPressedButtonColor(int pressedButtonColor) {
    this.pressedButtonColor = pressedButtonColor;
}

public Drawable getPressedDrawable() {
    return pressedDrawable;
}

public void setPressedDrawable(Drawable pressedDrawable) {
    this.pressedDrawable = pressedDrawable;
}

public Drawable getUnpressedDrawable() {
    return unpressedDrawable;
}

public void setUnpressedDrawable(Drawable unpressedDrawable) {
    this.unpressedDrawable = unpressedDrawable;
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="FlatButton">
        <attr name="buttonColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="cornerRadius" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

dimens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="flatbutton_default_corner_radius">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="flatbutton_default_padding_left">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="flatbutton_default_padding_right">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="flatbutton_default_padding_top">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="flatbutton_default_padding_bottom">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="flatbutton_default_height">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="flatbutton_default_text_size">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: Add the Xml files too

Comment: why calling `obtainStyledAttributes` twice?

Comment: nearly two month have passed.. do you solved the issue? i'm interested in the solution too